# Huawei 3G Dongle

Tags: wireless

Ubuntu connects to Vodacom network and works fine, but cant see utility window that shows usage or any other information

Comment: What utility do you mean ? If it is a windows utility, then, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [download-monitor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/download-monitor/)

```
sudo apt-get install download-monitor
```

This software Monitors your network usage to help you stay within usage caps.

You can also set a cap on your usage if you need to.